# Externalizing weblogic.xml file from war in weblogic12c

Tags: jakarta-ee, server, weblogic12c

We have requirement to externalize weblogic.xml. Because prod environment requires different settings than the non prod environments. We have a structure already placed for build once and deploy many. So once code changes are done war file is created and then same war file is deployed in different environments.So the ideal way would be to externalize weblogic.xml from the war file.
How to do this weblogic12c? Is there any method I can read weblogic.xml file from external location? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Weblogic's deployment plan functionality. Admittedly it does not enable to externalize config descriptors like weblogic.xml but it allows to override settings in those descriptors. So you could create such plan for each environment where you need to apply custom settings.
 
See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24443/config.htm#DEPGD169

Comment: Thanks slwk, although I cannot externalize weblogic.xml but my problem is solved. Link explains it all.